# In catalog item there is variable, with 100 text ,I have to add a scroll bar

Tags: scroll, addition, catalog

I have created a variable in catalog item which is auto-populated by selecting a requested for and also populating 100 word text in that variable i need to **add a scroll bar** please help me how to achieve this
optional with - Client script
or any other.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppBOk.png)
In this attached link I want scroll bar on right side.

I have tried with widget to add scroll bar with html codes but its unable to add them
please help me to find the solution.